# how to set subtitle in dygraph?

Tags: r, dygraphs

guys.

How to set a subtitle in dygraph? I tried several methods, but couldn't meet the result.

```
dygraph(df, main = "main", subtitle = "subtitle")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add line break to get two lines of the main

```
dygraph(xts(rnorm(200), seq(200) + Sys.time()),
        main='First line <br> second line')
```

Then you can play with changing the font size of the second line, e.g. using `<small>`

```
dygraph(xts(rnorm(200), seq(200) + Sys.time()),
        main='First line <br> <small>second line</small>')
```

Comment: great! Thanks a lot.

Comment: sorry, I have one more question. how to set the subtitle color?

Comment: Probably using typical css styling will do the job. Try: `<small style="color:red"> second line </small>`

Comment: Emmm, it raises an error, doesn't work.  "unexpected token: color"

Comment: Hmm... and what about `<small><font color="red">second line</font></small>`? (I cannot test it now...)

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. As changed double quotes ("") with single quotes(''), both of your codes worked well. Many thanks!!!